# Maximizing $x^k (1-x)^{n-k}$ without calculus

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Is there some trick that can be used to show that $x^k (1-x)^{n-k}$ over $[0, 1]$ is maximized at $x=\frac{k}{n}$ **without using derivatives**?

Comment: Some thoughts: I assume $n>k>0$. Then set $t=k/n$. Your expression becomes $x^{nt}(1-x)^{n(1-t)}$. Taking logs, $n[t\log x+(1-t)\log(1-x)]$. So your problem is now to show that $t\log x+(1-t)\log(1-x)$ has a maximum at $x=t$. The function $f(x,t)=t\log x+(1-t)\log(1-x)$ satisfies the symmetry $f(x,t)=f(1-x,1-t)$ and is defined on the square $(x,t)\in [0,1]\times [0,1]$. Can this be used to conclude that the maximum must occur along the line $x=t$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the geometric-arithmetic mean inequality, you get that
$$
(ax)^k·(1-x)^{n-k}\le\left(\frac{k·(ax)+(n-k)·(1-x)}n\right)^n
$$
with equality iff $ax=(1-x)$. To get the right side constant, use $a=\frac{n-k}{k}$ so that equality and thus the maximum happens for
$$
(n-k)x=k(1-x)\iff x=\frac kn
$$

Comment: Perfect, thanks for this.